# VueJS Вывод html через функцию

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Вообщем у меня есть функция которая выводит знаки валют, выглядит это так:

```
getSymbolCurrency (currency) {
  let symbol = null;

  switch (currency) {
    case 'RUB':
    case 'BYN':
      symbol = '&#8381;';
      break
    case 'USD':
    case 'AUD':
    case 'HKD':
    case 'CAD':
    case 'SGD':
      symbol = '&#36;';
      break
    case 'EUR':
      symbol = '&euro;';
      break
    case 'GBP':
      symbol = '&#163;';
      break
    case 'AMD':
      symbol = '&#1423;';
      break
    case 'BGN':
      symbol = 'лв';
      break
    case 'BRL':
      symbol = '&#82;';
      break
    case 'HUF':
      symbol = 'Ft';
      break
    case 'DKK':
      symbol = 'kr';
      break
    case 'INR':
      symbol = '&#8360;';
      break
    case 'KZT':
      symbol = '&#8376;';
      break
    case 'KGS':
      symbol = 'сом';
      break
    case 'CNY':
    case 'JPY':
      symbol = '&yen;';
      break
    case 'MDL':
      symbol = 'MDL';
      break
    case 'NOK':
      symbol = '&#107;';
      break
    case 'PLN':
      symbol = 'zł';
      break
    case 'RON':
      symbol = 'lei';
      break
    case 'XDR':
      symbol = 'XDR';
      break
    case 'TJS':
      symbol = 'смн.';
      break
    case 'TRY':
      symbol = '&#8378;';
      break
    case 'TMT':
      symbol = 'TMT';
      break
    case 'UZS':
      symbol = 'сўм';
      break
    case 'UAH':
      symbol = '&#8372;';
      break
    case 'CZK':
      symbol = '&#75;';
      break
    case 'SEK':
      symbol = '&#114;';
      break
    case 'CHF':
      symbol = '&#8355;';
      break
    case 'ZAR':
      symbol = 'R';
      break
    case 'KRW':
      symbol = '&#8361;';
      break
    default:
      symbol = '&#8381;';
  }

  return symbol;
},
```

Суть проблемы в том, что знаки хранятся как html и то как они находятся здесь немного не правильно т.к. они выведутся как тескст и преобразованы не будут, не все конечно, но большинство.
И вот вопрос как их правильно вывести, чтобы они преобразовались как html и в итоге показался знак??

Comment: А как вы их сейчас выводите? Вроде через v-html нужно.

Answer (score 0):

как вариант можно вместо html символов использовать unicode, например строчку '&n bsp;' нужно заменить на '\u00A0'